# Cannot get each item context for with a window resize inside a jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

So here I have a window resize event in my init. but if I have multiple boxes. It only references the last one. So in this example I ask me to alert when on of the two divs are less than 800. It doesn't work because it only makes reference to the last div.

Do I need to do an each with jquery? how to get each element that has been initated

https://codepen.io/stephenbe/pen/vdRPrW

Here is the codepen you can try it yourself.

```js
/*!
 * jQuery lightweight plugin boilerplate
 * Original author: @ajpiano
 * Further changes, comments: @addyosmani
 * Licensed under the MIT license
 */

// the semi-colon before the function invocation is a safety
// net against concatenated scripts and/or other plugins
// that are not closed properly.
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    // undefined is used here as the undefined global
    // variable in ECMAScript 3 and is mutable (i.e. it can
    // be changed by someone else). undefined isn't really
    // being passed in so we can ensure that its value is
    // truly undefined. In ES5, undefined can no longer be
    // modified.

    // window and document are passed through as local
    // variables rather than as globals, because this (slightly)
    // quickens the resolution process and can be more
    // efficiently minified (especially when both are
    // regularly referenced in your plugin).

    // Create the defaults once
    var pluginName = "defaultPluginName",
        defaults = {
            propertyName: "value"
        };

    // The actual plugin constructor
    function Plugin( element, options ) {
      console.log(element);
        that = this;
        this.element = element;

        // jQuery has an extend method that merges the
        // contents of two or more objects, storing the
        // result in the first object. The first object
        // is generally empty because we don't want to alter
        // the default options for future instances of the plugin
        this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options) ;

        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;

        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {

        init: function() {
            // Place initialization logic here
            // You already have access to the DOM element and
            // the options via the instance, e.g. this.element
            // and this.options
            // you can add more functions like the one below and
            // call them like so: this.yourOtherFunction(this.element, this.options).
          
          this.events();
        },

        events: function(el, options) {
            $(window).resize(that.doStuff);
        },
        
        doStuff: function() {
          console.log($(this.element).width());
          if($(that.element).width() < 800) {
            alert("hey its smaller then 300");
          }
        }
    };

    // A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor,
    // preventing against multiple instantiations
    $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName,
                new Plugin( this, options ));
            }
        });
    };

})( jQuery, window, document );

$('.box').defaultPluginName();

$('.box2').defaultPluginName();
```

```css
.box, .box2 {
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
  margin:10px;
}


.box2 {
  width:900px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box2"></div>
```

Edit :

I figured out a solution :

```
$(that.element).each(function(){
    var _that = $(this);
    var listItems = _that.find('li');
    $(window).resize(function() {
        console.log(_that);

        that.refreshMaxItems(_that, listItems)
    });
})
```

I added this in the event and it worked.

Comment: Not sure why you'd need an each in this case since you're just using `div` tags. Try this:  `if($('div').width() < 800) { alert("hey its smaller then 800"); } }`

Comment: that would not work because remember this is a jquery plugin. if someone adds this plugin, it will not work if you just add $('div')